# How to call Command from DataTemplate Entry TextChanged Event in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, datatemplate, relativesource, eventtocommand

Using DataTemplates in a CollectionView...
I can call a ViewModel's Command from a button like this:

```
<Button Text="Test"
    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}},
                      Path=BindingContext.TestCommand}"/>
```

Or from a gesture like this:

```
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}, Path=BindingContext.TestCommand}"/>        
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

So, why can't I call that command from an Entry's TextChanged Event like this?

```
<Entry x:Name="PortionEntry"
    Text ="{Binding QtyTest, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behavors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="TextChanged"
            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}},
                              Path=BindingContext.TestCommand}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
```

*The code for* EventToCommandBehavior *works when not used in a DataTemplate*

Here is a project illustrating the issue:
https://github.com/BullCityCabinets/DataTemplateEventIssue

I got the button code form these fine folks:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11029/how-to-bind-command-from-viewmodel-to-external-itemtemplate-of-xamarin-forms-listview

Thanks!

Comment: can you add your event to command behavior

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the above code does not call TestCommand.  Is there something else to check?  The xaml doesn't have any code behind, because it's a DataTemplate... and I get all sorts of errors when I try to add a DataTemplate with a cs backer... it doesn't seem possible.  Any advice?

Comment: @ScumSprocket What error message you have? You mean that it works fine when you use Entry, but have some problem when use in DataTemplate for EventToCommandBehavior?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't call the command when an Event occurs.  In following the MS Docs, I don't have any cs code-behind for the DataTemplate, so I'm not sure how else to test it.  I am using the exact same EventToCommandBehavior code in another area of the project that does not involve a DataTemplate, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at your example code and you appear to be using the [Xamarin Forms Example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior/) to implement your `EventToCommandBehavior`. This is also implemented in the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit) in roughly the same manner. **Note** that these implementations inherit from `Xamarin.Forms.Behavior`.

I also tried these examples to perform a Relative Source binding in a `DataTemplate` assigned to an `ItemsView` but when I would run the example (same as yours above) I would receive an `InvalidOperationException` at:

> Xamarin.Forms.Binding.ApplyRelativeSourceBinding
> (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject targetObject,
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty) [0x0006c] in
> C:\Advanced Dev\Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Binding.cs:158

Heading over to the [Xamarin source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/ff7695f214af79bd292f108abc2175131b9a2525/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Binding.cs#L158) you can see that the throw is a result of the binding `targetObject` not inheriting from `Xamarin.Forms.Element` when applying the binding in `Binding.ApplyRelativeSourceBinding()`. Since `EventToCommandBehavior` inherits from `Xamarin.Forms.Behavior` this is the result.

The [Xamarin Relative Binding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) don't specifically mention that the Binding *Target* requirement, they concern themselves with the binding *Source* obviously. But they do mention that these bindings search the Visual Tree or are relative to the Element:

> `FindAncestor` indicates the ancestor in the visual tree of the bound element.

> `Self` indicates the element on which the binding is being set,

Since a `Behavior` isn't an `Element` and isn't part of the Visual Tree (It's stored in the `VisualElement.Behaviors` property), the binding doesn't have direct access to either to perform it's "search" during runtime and thus the binding can't ever be satisfied.

I solved this by extending Entry and adding commands where needed. It's not the most reusable solution since I have to do it on other Elements like Switch but it works.

```
public class Entry : Xamarin.Forms.Entry
{
    public Entry()
    {
        this.TextChanged += this.OnTextChanged;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextChangedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( Entry.TextChangedCommand ), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( Entry ) );

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextChangedCommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( Entry.TextChangedCommandParameter ), typeof( object ), typeof( Entry ) );

    public ICommand TextChangedCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)this.GetValue( Entry.TextChangedCommandProperty );
        set => this.SetValue( Entry.TextChangedCommandProperty, (object)value );
    }

    public object TextChangedCommandParameter
    {
        get => this.GetValue( Entry.TextChangedCommandParameterProperty );
        set => this.SetValue( Entry.TextChangedCommandParameterProperty, value );
    }

    private void OnTextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( this.TextChangedCommand == null ||
             !this.TextChangedCommand.CanExecute( this.TextChangedCommandParameter ) )
            return;

        this.TextChangedCommand.Execute( this.TextChangedCommandParameter );
    }
}
```

And the xaml embedded inside a `DataTemplate`:

```
    <my:Entry Grid.Column="1"
           Text="{Binding Value}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
           Keyboard='Text'
           ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
           TextChangedCommand="{Binding BindingContext.TextChangedCommand, Mode=OneTime, Source={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsView}}}"
           TextChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" >
    </my:Entry>
```

**Update:**
After a few days of experimentation I've found another possible pattern to support this in a more generic fashion. I'll leave it up to the reader to decide on it's merits. I'm currently inclined to think it's a reasonable paradigm and is generic so there's no need to extend a bunch of existing Visual Elements.

The code presented below models the idea of an Observer that holds the command and observes an event of it's child. The parent/observer extends the bland `Xamarin.Forms.ContentView` element with the Command/CommandParameter/Converter that we see implemented in the [Xamarin Forms Example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior/) and combines that with an [Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties) implementation for the EventName.

The `ContentView.Content` property holds a single `Xamarin.Forms.View` object so there's no confusion with respect to the target of the Attached property. Event Handlers are all static so there shouldn't be any leaking issues.

```
public class EventToCommandObserver : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached( "EventName",
        typeof( string ), typeof( View ), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged );

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( Command ), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( EventToCommandObserver ) );

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( CommandParameter ), typeof( object ), typeof( EventToCommandObserver ) );

    public static readonly BindableProperty EventArgsConverterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create( nameof( EventArgsConverter ), typeof( IValueConverter ),
            typeof( EventToCommandObserver ) );

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue( CommandProperty ); }
        set { this.SetValue( CommandProperty, value ); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return this.GetValue( CommandParameterProperty ); }
        set { this.SetValue( CommandParameterProperty, value ); }
    }

    public IValueConverter EventArgsConverter
    {
        get { return (IValueConverter)this.GetValue( EventArgsConverterProperty ); }
        set { this.SetValue( EventArgsConverterProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static string GetEventName( BindableObject bindable )
    {
        return (string)bindable.GetValue( EventNameProperty );
    }

    public static void SetEventName( BindableObject bindable, string value )
    {
        bindable.SetValue( EventNameProperty, value );
    }

    private static void OnEventNameChanged( BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue )
    {
        DeregisterEvent( oldValue as string, bindable );

        RegisterEvent( newValue as string, bindable );
    }

    private static void RegisterEvent( string name, object associatedObject )
    {
        if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( name ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        EventInfo eventInfo = associatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent( name );

        if ( eventInfo == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( $"EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{name}' event." );
        }

        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof( EventToCommandObserver ).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod( "OnEvent" );

        Delegate eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate( eventInfo.EventHandlerType );

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler( associatedObject, eventHandler );
    }

    private static void DeregisterEvent( string name, object associatedObject )
    {
        if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( name ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        EventInfo eventInfo = associatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent( name );

        if ( eventInfo == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( $"EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{name}' event." );
        }

        MethodInfo methodInfo =
            typeof( EventToCommandObserver ).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod( nameof( OnEvent ) );

        Delegate eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate( eventInfo.EventHandlerType );

        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler( associatedObject, eventHandler );
    }

    private static void OnEvent( object sender, object eventArgs )
    {
        if ( ( (View)sender ).Parent is EventToCommandObserver commandView )
        {
            ICommand command = commandView.Command;

            if ( command == null )
            {
                return;
            }

            object resolvedParameter;

            if ( commandView.CommandParameter != null )
            {
                resolvedParameter = commandView.CommandParameter;
            }
            else if ( commandView.EventArgsConverter != null )
            {
                resolvedParameter =
                    commandView.EventArgsConverter.Convert( eventArgs, typeof( object ), null, null );
            }
            else
            {
                resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
            }

            if ( command.CanExecute( resolvedParameter ) )
            {
                command.Execute( resolvedParameter );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this alternate xaml embedded inside a `DataTemplate`:

```
        <my:EventToCommandObserver Grid.Column="1"
                                   Command="{Binding BindingContext.TextChangedCommand, Mode=OneTime, Source={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsView}}}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneTime}">
            <Entry Text="{Binding Value}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Keyboard='Text'
                   ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                   my:EventToCommandObserver .EventName="TextChanged" />
        </my:EventToCommandObserver >
```

Comment: Seems like the answer is in there, somewhere... I can't wait to get back to my favorite problems!

Comment: @ScumSprocket Sorry if it turned into TL;DR. Didn't think 2 answers was the way to go. Top section describes why the RelativeSource binding doesn't work for Behavior and suggest individual implementations which isn't all that wonderful but works. That's where I started. Bottom presents an alternative and more generic possible solution which I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code, if I don't use relative source binding, it can works fine.

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo3.simplecontrol2.Page2"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:customcontrol="clr-namespace:demo3.customcontrol"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demo3.simplecontrol2"
x:Name="root">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="datatemplate1">
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Text="{Binding str, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <local:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference root}, Path=BindingContext.command1}" EventName="TextChanged" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>

    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
       

        <Entry Text="123">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <local:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding command1}" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>

        <CollectionView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource datatemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding entries}">
           
        </CollectionView>


      
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<testentry> entries { get; set; }

    
   public Command command1 { get; set; }

  
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        entries = new ObservableCollection<testentry>()
        {
            new testentry(){str="test 1"},
            new testentry(){str="test 2"},
            new testentry(){str="test 3"},
            new testentry(){str="test 4"},
            new testentry(){str="test 5"},
            new testentry(){str="test 6"}

        };

        command1 = new Command(testcommand);
       
        

        this.BindingContext = this;

       
    }
   
    private void testcommand()
    {
       
        Console.WriteLine("this is test!");
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Bu, the DataTemplate is in a DataTemplateSelector... I'm sorry I didn't make that more apparent.  I have attached a project on GitHub to help.

Comment: @ScumSprocket If you have one solution on github, please share your link here, thanks.

Comment: Here is a project... the Template file is MyDataTemplate1.xaml, and you can see a CutomEntry I tried, as well.  The CustomEntry doens't appear at all, when in a DataTemplate.  I added some yellow indicators to show the tap gestures work... I can't understand why the entry text changed doens't fire, though. https://github.com/BullCityCabinets/DataTemplateEventIssue

Comment: @ScumSprocket I try your sample, you mean that the customentry TextChangedCommand don't fire when customentry text changed?

Comment: correct.  I can make other things work, just not TextChanged on the Entry.  I am actually rebuilding the pages in C# to see if I can create an event (since the DataTemplate doesn't have a cs file).